# How to theme remote modules in micro-frontend?

Tags: material-ui

I have an Nx micro-frontend project that uses React and MUI and I am attempting to theme the host/container app and have that provide the theme to all children of the host/container.

However, I have ran into some issues when I attempt to import MUI components certain ways I get warnings in the console or the theme not being shared to the children. This seems to depend on the way I import the ThemeProvider and the MUI components.

If I use the ThemeProvider from "@mui/material/styles" with named MUI imports, the theme doesn't apply! And if use default imports, I get a warning:

> You are loading @emotion/react when it is already loaded. Running multiple instances may cause problems. This can happen if multiple versions are used, or if multiple builds of the same version are used.

(and the remote theme isn't affected anyway)

If I use the ThemeProvider from "@mui/material" and use named imports, then everything works as expected.

However I'd prefer not to import all @mui and use default imports for each component.

Is there a correct way to have MUI and MFEs have a single theme AND have default imports?

Comment: Can you just export the theme (JSON) from the host app and have the remotes consume it via their own `ThemeProvider`s?

Comment: In some scenarios I think that is a valid solution. However, for this setup, there is always going to be a point where there will be some sort of a "container" that is housing the pieces of the MFE and both the container and the remotes need to be themed. 
Note, I tried something like this - each MFE using a ThemeProvider - but the same limitations still apply (emotion warning, named imports only, etc.)